# How to ignore\disable the anchor in a HTML HRef with a hash in the title

Tags: html

I have the following code to link to HTML pages held in C:\Test sub-folders.

```
<a href= "M/Index.html">M stuff</a><br />
<a href= "X#/Index.html">X# stuff</a><br />
<a href= "c:/Test/X#/Index.html">X# stuff</a><br />
```

Browsers are unable to find the `X#` index file via the second line. The only solution I have found is to specify the full path (as in line three).

I realise this problem is caused by the `#` symbol in the `href` property. Is there any way to allow the hash symbol to be part of the location reference as in my example without specifying the full path name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at url-encoding You need to encode the `#` so that it is read as a simple character. Take a look at [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) for some more information.

> **Percent-encoding** is a mechanism to encode 8-bit characters that have specific meaning in the context of URLs. It is sometimes called URL encoding. The encoding consists of substitution: A '%' followed by the hexadecimal representation of the ASCII value of the replace character.

In short, `#` can be encoded using `%23`, so:

```
<a href="X%23/Index.html">X# stuff</a>
```

Comment: Great, this does have the desired effect but I have noticed that on return from the linked page the colour does not change for either line two or three (as it does do for line one i.e. Usual default effect). I guess this is also due to the hash symbol. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: I have re-tested the process. Navigating back from the line one link does highlight the reference whereas it does not on the other two. I have tried  to up vote your answer but the system does not recognise me yet because my reputation is below 15.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer with the question @jcuenod. It works fine with Chrome (References are highlighted on return) and FireFox (References do not change on return). It is just MS Edge (and IE) which demonstrate the peculiar action.

Comment: @StuKay that makes sense, IE is renowned for having different implementations. One solution is to style `a:visited` links the same as `a` so that there is at least consistency (this is pretty common online).